# CCColor is null

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Hello for my game I need to be able to check the color of two sprites that collide.
I used this:

```
-(BOOL)ccPhysicsCollisionBegin:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair MainArrow:(ArrowSprite *)node ArrowFall:(ArrowSprite *)nodeB{
nodeB.physicsBody = nil;
if (lroundf(mainArrow2.position.x) == lroundf(nodeB.position.x) && [node.colorRGBA isEqualToColor:col]){
    [nodeB removeFromParent];
    [self scorePlusPLus];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:score forKey:@"Last_score"];
}
else if(!(lroundf(mainArrow2.position.x) == lroundf(nodeB.position.x))&& ![node.colorRGBA isEqualToColor:col]){

}
else{
    NSLog(@"%@",nodeB.color);
    //This outputs (null)


    [self setHighScoreOnMindBend];
    self.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [nodeB stopAllActions];

    runGame = NO;
    CCActionScaleBy *scale = [CCActionScaleBy actionWithDuration:.5 scale:1.5];
    CCActionScaleBy *scales = [CCActionScaleBy actionWithDuration:.5 scale:1/1.5];
    CCActionCallFunc *end = [CCActionCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(endGame)];

    CCActionSequence *seq = [CCActionSequence actionWithArray:@[scale,scales,scale,end]];
    [nodeB runAction:seq];
}


return YES;
}
```

The problem is that nodeB.color is null.
I did set the color and I can output the color just fine a different function.Setting the nodeB to nil doesn't cause it to become null I tried that.